# Qt - Move OpenGL Rendering from main thread to a different thread

Tags: multithreading, qt, opengl, rendering

I'm aware of the fact that QWidgets cannot be moved from the main thread to another thread in Qt. I have a main GUI that has three different QGLWidgets that render different OpenGl content. As expected the framerate of the QGLWidgets suffers significantly when showing all three at the same time but the GUI itself responds very fast and when I look at the CPU usage, I observe that the main thread is only running at 50% CPU load. I would expect better performance if I could move the rendering to different threads but how can I do this as Qt doesn't allow that?

PS: I use different timers which call the animate() method at a desired framerate. Is that a problem? The timers don't achieve their configured firing frequency (= desired fps), the run at a max. of ~15Hz but as I said, the GUI doesn't lag and the main thread doesn't run at full CPU load.

Answer (score 0):

You can place the rendering methods in different threads with: `QtConcurrent::run`.
http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtconcurrentrun.html#run

Comment: Unfortunately this is not enough, since you need the thread binding the OpenGL context.